# Where to locate resolv.conf file in CentOS 7

Tags: resolv.conf

I know that "/etc/resolv.conf" is auto generated file by "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head" when reboot Ubuntu 14.04. It's ok

But where i can locate same "/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head" file in CentOS 7 ?

## UPDATE

Content of file /etc/resolv.conf

```
**# Generated by NetworkManager**
search reesu.co.in
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

But I want to see this content:

```
**# Generated by NetworkManager**
search domain.tld
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

OR

```
**# Generated by NetworkManager**
**#search reesu.co.in**
search domain.tld
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

after every reboot:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

In other words, `resolv.conf` is either generated by `NetworkManager` if you have it installed or you have to configure it yourself.

I've had that problem with `Redhat` servers where I wanted to keep `NetworkManager` from overwriting my static configuration of `resolv.conf` so I ended up setting my configuration in `resolv.conf` then changing the attributes to **read-only** like so

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

**NOTE**: you will have to do `chattr -i` before being able to change the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` in the future.

Comment: Content of file /etc/resolv.conf

# Generated by NetworkManager
search reesu.co.in
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

But i want to see content in file /etc/resolv.conf:

# Generated by NetworkManager
search domain.tld
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

OR

# Generated by NetworkManager
#search reesu.co.in
search domain.tld
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

after every reboot:

Comment: @RinkuYadav here's your solution. It works like a charm.

Comment: Better : i need to manually update file /etc/resolv.conf. And i will never stop VPS server. Any other better idea please share if you have.

Comment: imagine that this is due to the hostname of the server. Please feel free to change it in /etc/hostname and /etc/sysconfig/network to domain.tld as needed. Someone told me.

Comment: This is due to `NetworkManager` auto-generating the file. Why do you need to change it ? You can write a script to change it for you if you like.

Answer (score 3):

In CentOS, you add entries to:

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

You can add up to two DNS entries in the ifcfg-eth* file as, for example:

`DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=4.4.4.4`

[Official source](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html)